# Problem taking different values from form

Tags: php, jquery, select

I'm doing a form in PHP. I started using jQuery to make a select dropdown more interactive. Depending on your option, you will receive a new select dropdown with other options. The problem comes when you take the first option, the value is always the same.

```js
$('#options').on('change', function(e) {
  $('.option').hide();
  $('#option-' + e.target.value).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label>Contract type</label>

  <select id="options" class="form-control" name="typeContract" required>
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select options </option>
    <option value="light">Light</option>
    <option value="gas">Gas</option>
  </select>
  <div id="option-light" class="option" style="display: none;">
    <br>
    <select class="form-control" name="nameContract" required>
      <option value="light1">1</option>
      <option value="light2">2</option>
      <option value="light3">3</option>
    </select>

  </div>

  <div id="option-gas" class="option" style="display: none;">
    <br>
    <select class="form-control" name="nameContract" required>
      <option value="gas1">gas1</option>
      <option value="gas2">gas2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please note that you should never have multiple values with the same ID, ID must be unique

Comment: Also this part `$('#option-'` would suggest that you had an element with the id `option-` + something, but no element has an id starting with `option-`

Answer (score 0):

You were very close.
But the jquery code tried to show an element with the id `option-light` or `option-gas` which do not exist in your code. So if you change your id's it works. 
As pointed out by Carsten in the comments `id` should always be unique

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label>Contract type</label>

  <select id="options" class="form-control" name="typeContract"  required>
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select options </option>
    <option value="light">Light</option>
    <option value="gas">Gas</option>
  </select>
  <div id="option-light" class="option"  style="display: none;">
    <br>
    <select class="form-control" name="nameContract" required>
      <option value="light1">1</option>
      <option value="light2">2</option>
      <option value="light3">3</option>
    </select>

  </div>

  <div id="option-gas" class="option"  style="display: none;">
    <br>
    <select class="form-control" name="nameContract" required>
      <option value="gas1">gas1</option>
      <option value="gas2">gas2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! is working, but now the broblem is that always is saving de value from de select gas... When i select light, and its display another select with light, it save gas value dont know why..

Comment: This probably also has something today with things having the same name (`nameContract`). Even though an element is hidden, the data is still being send with the form. So it tries to send two different values under the same name